# How to ignore empty parquet files when reading multiple parquets from one location

Tags: file, apache-spark, dataframe, parquet, bigdata

I am trying to read parquet files to a dataframe, like that

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("<location>/*.parquet")
```

However, under  directory, there may exists empty parquet file (which size is 0 Byte). Is there an efficient way it can ignore reading empty file?

Comment: do you see any issue with data frame while processing empty files ? it will just ignore them anyway.

Comment: No, it won't ignore the empty files, I said empty I mean it doesn't even have the schema. If the dataframe reads multiple files with different schema, it would fail.

Comment: can you tell me what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time here but the question has not been answered :)

If you have more files in your location and at least one file is > 0 Bytes, you may merge the schema.

Example in pyspark:

The following code:

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(location)
```

will fail with

```
"Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually"
```

error if you have at least one 0 Bytes file. However,

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("mergeSchema", "true").load(location)
```

will succeed if you have at least one file > 0 Bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This method did solve the problem with two of my partitions so I was very optimistic about the solution. However, when I plugged in all other partitions to it, I'm hitting the same problem. I've read the spark documentation about mergeSchema and I still don't have the answer. In hindsight: I have three files in that partition, two of them have a few MB and one is empty. Any further ideas?